# useEffect calls stop working when called too many times. Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I have a useEffect, which works properly when done like this.

```
    async function readUserPosts(profileID){
        try {
            const res = await axios.post(...);
            setUserPosts(res.data.posts);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        readUserPosts(profileID);   
    }, [profileID])
```

But, if I define the same useEffect by adding a second function like this:

```
    async function readUserPosts(profileID){
        try {
            const res = await axios.post(...);
            setUserPosts(res.data.posts);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        readUserPosts(profileID);
        functionX();
    }, [profileID])
```

The useEffect works the first few times I reload the page, after which it stops working. I do not get any error message, even when I wrap the try catch around the 2 functions. FunctionX is a simple async function. I have substituted other test functions on functionX, and it produces the same result. So basically, it will not work when a second function is defined. What went wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "few"? useEffect is called every time when any element of his dependency list has been changed. In your case, it's a profileID. So, it must be called as many times as profileId has been changed.

Comment: Yea, as I change the userID, it works the first few times, but afterwards it stops working even as I change the userID.

Comment: Could you make an example on the codesandbox or something like this? Or try putting console.log/debugger in useEffect, to make sure it really doesn't get called.

Comment: Hard to make an example, and when i console.logged on the useEffect, I got nothing. But, I'll describe more: so the profileID here is fetched from useParams, so if I click on other records the profileID changes, and renders for different profiles. As I click on different records, it works and calls the 2 functions properly but as I keep changing the userID, suddenly it would stop working.

Comment: Although the useEffect works, when I have only 1 function inside of it.

Comment: What is userId? In your example I saw only profileId.

Comment: Btw, did you see some warnings or errors in console?

Comment: It's solved with the first answer. Thanks a lot for your time anyway. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the two methods with useCallback. Here is one method for example:

```
const readUserPosts = useCallback(async function() {
  try {
        const res = await axios.post(...);
        setUserPosts(res.data.posts);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
 }, []);
```

And try with adding dependency like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    readUserPosts(profileID);
    functionX();
}, [profileID, readUserPosts, functionX])
```

Comment: Here is a code sandbox with fake api calls:

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-nova-yh69sm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I got this to work, but I had to add userID as the dependency for the 2 functions. Thanks.